# font size bug with CGContextShowTextAtPoint

Tags: macos, cocoa, text

I have some rather simple code drawing some text into a CGContext. Here is an excerpt (slightly edited).

```
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Helvetica", 1.5, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, xpos, ypos, "Hello", 5);
```

The text renders ok. For some unknown reason, however, the font changes to a smaller size after I click in the view containing the context. Also when I resize the window containing the view the font returns to original size. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

1.5 points is mighty tiny to begin with. Assuming no other scaling is in effect, that will be one whole pixel and a blurry pixel above it on the screen.

You're probably seeing a bug that I ran into myself: On entry into `drawRect:`, the current context's text matrix was not the identity matrix. In my case, I saw it contain a scale by 13 on both axes, plus a translation. (Possibly left over from drawing the title bar.) I filed this in Radar as #10585106, in case you want to [file your own](https://bugreport.apple.com/) and cite it.

The solution is to [set the text matrix](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetTextMatrix) back to [the identity transform](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGAffineTransformIdentity) before trying to draw text.

Once you do that, you'll find that your text will be exactly as tiny as you asked for it to be. You should change your font size to something more reasonable; [Core Text contains a function to get the system fonts](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFontRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage) (from which you can [get their sizes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFontRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFontGetSize)), and [AppKit's NSFont class contains methods for the same purpose](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000382-DontLinkElementID_12).

Comment: Yes the solution was setting the the text matrix to the identity transform. Figured it out shortly after posting. This isn't necessary on iOS so it was slightly surprising.

Comment: @RubenZilibowitz: It shouldn't be necessary on Mac OS X, either, which is why I filed a bug and recommend that you do the same.